# Ideals with infinitely many generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As the title may suggest, I am not sure if I understand the ideals with infinitely many generators correctly. Let us take the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots]$ and consider the ideal $(x_1,x_2,x_3\dots)$ generated by all the indeterminates in the polynomial ring $R$. As a set
\begin{equation}
(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)=\{f_1x_1+f_2x_2+f_3x_3+\dots|f_1,f_2,f_3,\dots\in R\}.
\end{equation}
My understanding is that the $+$ in the above notation does not stand for the ring operation (we can't add infinitely many elements) and that $f_1x_1+f_2x_2+f_3x_3+\dots$ is an element of $R$ and so automatically only finitely many $f_i\neq0_R$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Rather only finitely many coefficients can be non-zero.

Comment: Of course, edited, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing $$(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)=\{f_1x_1+f_2x_2+f_3x_3+\dots|f_1,f_2,f_3,\dots\in R\}$$ is rather imprecise, because (as you said), you cannot add infinitely many elements in a ring (unless you have a topology). It would be better to write instead
$$
(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) = \left\{\sum_{i\geq 1} f_i x_i\mid f_i\in R\textrm{ and }f_i = 0\textrm{ for all but finitely many }i\right\}.
$$
The sum in the set on the right hand side is now well-defined, and this is the ideal that you want.

Comment: Thank you! What if I take the ring $\mathbb{Z}[[x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots]]$ of formal power series with each monomial allowed to have only finitely many non-zero powers? What would $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ be then?

Comment: I would just be the same, right?

Comment: The definition given above does not depend on the ring R, but is a general definition for an ideal generated by a subset. (In short you are right)

Comment: Great, thanks !

Comment: Isn't it easier to say $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) = \sum_{1\leq i\leq j, j \in N}{f_{i}x_{i}: f_{i} \in R}$? Or is it wrong somehow?

Comment: First of all the RHS has to be a set so you need curly brackets there. Also, I don't think that taking $j \in \mathbb{N}$ is enough. No matter how big your $j$ is, it is still a finite number but we have infinitely many variables. Writing $j \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ would probably solve that issue.

Comment: @amator2357 Louis is right, the definition would be the same. However, you could write the corresponding ideal for $\Bbb{Z}[\![x_1,x_2,\dots]\!]$ in a different, perhaps more suggestive way as
$$
\left\{\sum_{I\in\Bbb{N}_0^{\Bbb{N}}\setminus\{(0,0,0,\dots)\}}' n_I x^I\mid \forall m\geq 0, n_I = 0\textrm{ for all but finitely many }I = (e_1,e_2,\dots)\textrm{ with }\sum_{i\geq 1}e_i\leq m\right\}.
$$
The $\sum'$ indicates that the sum is to be taken over $I$ such that all but finitely many entries in $I$ are $0.$

Comment: [continued] Here, if $I = (e_1, e_2, e_3,\dots),$ then $x^I = \prod_{i\geq 1}x_i^{e_i}.$ The condition that all but finitely many entries of $I$ are zero implies that each term of the sum is well-defined and that $\sum_{i\geq 1}e_i$ is finite, and the condition that $n_I = 0$ for all but finitely many $I$ with $\sum_{i\geq 1}e_i\leq m$ implies that the sum is convergent (there are only finitely many terms of total degree less than or equal to $m$ for any $m$). This emphasizes the convergent power series aspect of the ideal.

Comment: that is indeed a much neater description @Stahl, thank you!

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind. What is the convergent power series aspect of the ideal?

Comment: @amator2357 All I mean is that generally when we write a power series, we write something like $x + 3x^2 + 5x^4 + \dots$ where the exponents are increasing. In the topology on $\Bbb{Z}[\![x]\!],$ $x^n$ is very small when $n\gg 0.$ In $\Bbb{Z}[\![x_1,\dots,]\!],$ monomials with high total degree will be very small. So I'm simply writing the power series in the ideal in a more standard way, as a sum of monomials, and the conditions imply that the sum converges (that there are only finitely many terms of total degree less than $m$ for any $m$).

Comment: @Stahl I see. Thanks for your help.